# Converting group of xml files to .mdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have worked previously on data driven website using asp. net and sql server. This involved retrieving records from the database and showing on the webpage. Now, I have some folders on server which have xml files. I have to create an Asp website that searches with folder names and retrieve other information from the particular xml file which is selected. I assume this will be easier if it is in database .mdf so that it can be accessed using sql server and through stored procedures to access the information in xml files..

Now the question is how to convert the xml files on server to .mdf to perform search operations on my asp website.. please guide me .. and one more thing is the folders will be updated daily...so,need something which does conversion during retrieval .. please guide me with best possible way

Comment: And what did you do to achieve this? 
Two words:
StreamReader, System.IO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 . Convert xml files to dataset
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10427/Convert-XML-Data-to-DataSet-and-Back

step 2. for each table in dataset create a table and insert those rows.

step 3. perform your queries on those tables

Or **simply use linq to xml** (Best In this senario), No need to convert directly query on xml